# Speed up mysql update

Tags: mysql, xml

I have to parse an xml file with around 20,000 items, and for each item I have to update several hundred rows in a mysql table on a date and an id.

I am doing 1 update for each item in the xml file.

Example update query:

```
UPDATE ljqfw_booking_availability set availability = 0 where unit_id=7520 and availdate in
  ("2014-09-13","2014-09-14","2014-09-15","2014-09-16","2014-09-17","2014-09-18","2014-09-19","2014-09-20","2014-09-21","2014-09-22","2014-09-23","2014-09-24","2014-09-25","2014-09-26","2014-09-27","2014-09-28","2014-09-29","2014-09-30","2014-10-01","2014-10-02","2014-10-03","2014-10-04","2014-10-05","2014-10-06","2014-10-07","2014-10-08","2014-10-09","2014-10-10","2014-10-11","2014-10-12","2014-10-13","2014-10-14","2014-10-15","2014-10-16","2014-10-17","2014-10-18","2014-10-19","2014-10-20","2014-10-21","2014-10-22","2014-10-23","2014-10-24","2014-10-25","2014-10-26","2014-10-27","2014-10-28","2014-10-29","2014-10-30","2014-10-31","2014-11-01","2014-11-02","2014-11-03","2014-11-04","2014-11-05","2014-11-06","2014-11-07","2014-11-08","2014-11-09","2014-11-10","2014-11-11","2014-11-12","2014-11-13","2014-11-14","2014-11-15","2014-11-16","2014-11-17","2014-11-18","2014-11-19","2014-11-20","2014-11-21","2014-11-22","2014-11-23","2014-11-24","2014-11-25","2014-11-26","2014-11-27","2014-11-28","2014-11-29","2014-11-30","2014-12-01","2014-12-02","2014-12-03","2014-12-04","2014-12-05","2014-12-06","2014-12-07","2014-12-08","2014-12-09","2014-12-10","2014-12-11","2014-12-12","2014-12-13","2014-12-14","2014-12-15","2014-12-16","2014-12-17","2014-12-18","2014-12-19","2014-12-20","2014-12-21","2014-12-22","2014-12-23","2014-12-24","2014-12-25","2014-12-26","2014-12-27","2014-12-28","2014-12-29","2014-12-30","2014-12-31","2015-01-01","2015-01-02","2015-01-24","2015-01-25","2015-01-26","2015-01-27","2015-01-28","2015-01-29","2015-01-30","2015-01-31","2015-02-01","2015-02-02","2015-02-03","2015-02-04","2015-02-05","2015-02-06","2015-02-14","2015-02-15","2015-02-16","2015-02-17","2015-02-18","2015-02-19","2015-02-20","2015-02-21","2015-02-22","2015-02-23","2015-02-24","2015-02-25","2015-02-26","2015-02-27","2015-03-07","2015-03-08","2015-03-09","2015-03-10","2015-03-11","2015-03-12","2015-03-13","2015-04-18","2015-04-19","2015-04-20","2015-04-21","2015-04-22","2015-04-23","2015-04-24","2015-04-25","2015-04-26","2015-04-27","2015-04-28","2015-04-29","2015-04-30","2015-05-01","2015-05-02","2015-05-03","2015-05-04","2015-05-05","2015-05-06","2015-05-07","2015-05-08","2015-05-09","2015-05-10","2015-05-11","2015-05-12","2015-05-13","2015-05-14","2015-05-15","2015-05-16","2015-05-17","2015-05-18","2015-05-19","2015-05-20","2015-05-21","2015-05-22","2015-05-23","2015-05-24","2015-05-25","2015-05-26","2015-05-27","2015-05-28","2015-05-29","2015-05-30","2015-05-31","2015-06-01","2015-06-02","2015-06-03","2015-06-04","2015-06-05","2015-06-06","2015-06-07","2015-06-08","2015-06-09","2015-06-10","2015-06-11","2015-06-12","2015-06-13","2015-06-14","2015-06-15","2015-06-16","2015-06-17","2015-06-18","2015-06-19","2015-06-20","2015-06-21","2015-06-22","2015-06-23","2015-06-24","2015-06-25","2015-06-26","2015-06-27","2015-06-28","2015-06-29","2015-06-30","2015-07-01","2015-07-02","2015-07-03","2015-07-04","2015-07-05","2015-07-06","2015-07-07","2015-07-08","2015-07-09","2015-07-10","2015-07-11","2015-07-12","2015-07-13","2015-07-14","2015-07-15","2015-07-16","2015-07-17","2015-07-18","2015-07-19","2015-07-20","2015-07-21","2015-07-22","2015-07-23","2015-07-24","2015-07-25","2015-07-26","2015-07-27","2015-07-28","2015-07-29","2015-07-30","2015-07-31","2015-08-01","2015-08-02","2015-08-03","2015-08-04","2015-08-05","2015-08-06","2015-08-07","2015-08-08","2015-08-09","2015-08-10","2015-08-11","2015-08-12","2015-08-13","2015-08-14","2015-08-15","2015-08-16","2015-08-17","2015-08-18","2015-08-19","2015-08-20","2015-08-21","2015-08-22","2015-08-23","2015-08-24","2015-08-25","2015-08-26","2015-08-27","2015-08-28","2015-08-29","2015-08-30","2015-08-31","2015-09-01","2015-09-02","2015-09-03","2015-09-04","2015-09-05","2015-09-06","2015-09-07","2015-09-08","2015-09-09","2015-09-10","2015-09-11","2015-09-12","2015-09-13","2015-09-14","2015-09-15","2015-09-16","2015-09-17","2015-09-18","2015-09-19","2015-09-20","2015-09-21","2015-09-22","2015-09-23","2015-09-24","2015-09-25","2015-09-26","2015-09-27","2015-09-28","2015-09-29","2015-09-30","2015-10-01","2015-10-02","2015-10-03","2015-10-04","2015-10-05","2015-10-06","2015-10-07","2015-10-08","2015-10-09","2015-10-10","2015-10-11","2015-10-12","2015-10-13","2015-10-14","2015-10-15","2015-10-16","2015-10-17","2015-10-18","2015-10-19","2015-10-20","2015-10-21","2015-10-22","2015-10-23","2015-10-24","2015-10-25","2015-10-26","2015-10-27","2015-10-28","2015-10-29","2015-10-30","2015-10-31","2015-11-01","2015-11-02","2015-11-03","2015-11-04","2015-11-05","2015-11-06","2015-11-07","2015-11-08","2015-11-09","2015-11-10","2015-11-11","2015-11-12","2015-11-13","2015-11-14","2015-11-15","2015-11-16","2015-11-17","2015-11-18","2015-11-19","2015-11-20","2015-11-21","2015-11-22","2015-11-23","2015-11-24","2015-11-25","2015-11-26","2015-11-27","2015-11-28","2015-11-29","2015-11-30","2015-12-01","2015-12-02","2015-12-03","2015-12-04","2015-12-05","2015-12-06","2015-12-07","2015-12-08","2015-12-09","2015-12-10","2015-12-11","2015-12-12","2015-12-13","2015-12-14","2015-12-15","2015-12-16","2015-12-17","2015-12-18","2015-12-19","2015-12-20","2015-12-21","2015-12-22","2015-12-23","2015-12-24","2015-12-25","2015-12-26","2015-12-27","2015-12-28","2015-12-29","2015-12-30","2015-12-31","2016-01-01","2016-01-02","2016-01-03","2016-01-04","2016-01-05","2016-01-06","2016-01-07","2016-01-08","2016-01-09","2016-01-10","2016-01-11","2016-01-12","2016-01-13","2016-01-14","2016-01-15","2016-01-16","2016-01-17","2016-01-18","2016-01-19","2016-01-20","2016-01-21","2016-01-22","2016-01-23","2016-01-24","2016-01-25","2016-01-26","2016-01-27","2016-01-28","2016-01-29","2016-01-30","2016-01-31","2016-02-01","2016-02-02","2016-02-03","2016-02-04","2016-02-05","2016-02-06","2016-02-07","2016-02-08","2016-02-09","2016-02-10","2016-02-11","2016-02-12","2016-02-13","2016-02-14","2016-02-15","2016-02-16","2016-02-17","2016-02-18","2016-02-19","2016-02-20","2016-02-21","2016-02-22","2016-02-23","2016-02-24","2016-02-25","2016-02-26","2016-02-27","2016-02-28","2016-02-29","2016-03-01","2016-03-02","2016-03-03","2016-03-04","2016-03-05","2016-03-06","2016-03-07","2016-03-08","2016-03-09","2016-03-10","2016-03-11","2016-03-12","2016-03-13","2016-03-14","2016-03-15","2016-03-16","2016-03-17","2016-03-18","2016-03-19","2016-03-20","2016-03-21","2016-03-22","2016-03-23","2016-03-24","2016-03-25","2016-03-26","2016-03-27","2016-03-28","2016-03-29","2016-03-30","2016-03-31","2016-04-01","2016-04-02","2016-04-03","2016-04-04","2016-04-05","2016-04-06","2016-04-07","2016-04-08","2016-04-09","2016-04-10","2016-04-11","2016-04-12","2016-04-13","2016-04-14","2016-04-15","2016-04-16","2016-04-17","2016-04-18","2016-04-19","2016-04-20","2016-04-21","2016-04-22","2016-04-23","2016-04-24","2016-04-25","2016-04-26","2016-04-27","2016-04-28","2016-04-29","2016-04-30","2016-05-01","2016-05-02","2016-05-03","2016-05-04","2016-05-05","2016-05-06","2016-05-07","2016-05-08","2016-05-09","2016-05-10","2016-05-11","2016-05-12","2016-05-13","2016-05-14","2016-05-15","2016-05-16","2016-05-17","2016-05-18","2016-05-19","2016-05-20","2016-05-21","2016-05-22","2016-05-23","2016-05-24","2016-05-25","2016-05-26","2016-05-27","2016-05-28","2016-05-29","2016-05-30","2016-05-31","2016-06-01","2016-06-02","2016-06-03","2016-06-04","2016-06-05","2016-06-06","2016-06-07","2016-06-08","2016-06-09","2016-06-10","2016-06-11","2016-06-12","2016-06-13","2016-06-14","2016-06-15","2016-06-16","2016-06-17","2016-06-18","2016-06-19","2016-06-20","2016-06-21","2016-06-22","2016-06-23","2016-06-24","2016-06-25","2016-06-26","2016-06-27","2016-06-28","2016-06-29","2016-06-30","2016-07-01","2016-07-02","2016-07-03","2016-07-04","2016-07-05","2016-07-06","2016-07-07","2016-07-08","2016-07-09","2016-07-10","2016-07-11","2016-07-12","2016-07-13","2016-07-14","2016-07-15","2016-07-16","2016-07-17","2016-07-18","2016-07-19","2016-07-20","2016-07-21","2016-07-22","2016-07-23","2016-07-24","2016-07-25","2016-07-26","2016-07-27","2016-07-28","2016-07-29","2016-07-30","2016-07-31","2016-08-01","2016-08-02","2016-08-03","2016-08-04","2016-08-05","2016-08-06","2016-08-07","2016-08-08","2016-08-09","2016-08-10","2016-08-11","2016-08-12","2016-08-13","2016-08-14","2016-08-15","2016-08-16","2016-08-17","2016-08-18","2016-08-19","2016-08-20","2016-08-21","2016-08-22","2016-08-23","2016-08-24","2016-08-25","2016-08-26","2016-08-27","2016-08-28","2016-08-29","2016-08-30","2016-08-31","2016-09-01","2016-09-02","2016-09-03","2016-09-04","2016-09-05","2016-09-06","2016-09-07","2016-09-08","2016-09-09","2016-09-10","2016-09-11","2016-09-12","2016-09-13")
```

Here is my table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ljqfw_booking_availability` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `available` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `season_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `availdate` date NOT NULL,
  `apt_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `unit_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `createdby` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `modified_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=10331615 ;
```

I need to run this script every 30 minutes, but it currently takes around 9 hours to run.
I have run a timer on the update query, and it takes between 0.3 and 0.6 seconds, the speed at which is parses the xml is very fast - it is the actual update query that is slow.

What could I do to make this faster?
I have an index on availdate to make retrieval faster, is this slowing down the update?

Comment: For better speed improvements, you may need to restructure your system. Why do you need to perform 20K updates every 30 minutes?

Comment: It is for availability for a booking system, and one of the requirements is that the availabity must be updated at least every 30 minutes. The xml file I have doesn't let me know what has changed since last update, just a long list of dates and whether it is available or not.

Comment: Each update uses `unit_id` and `availdate` for lookups, and then updates only the 'availability` column. Have you tried adding an index on `unit_id` and `availdate`?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer (if an index like this does not already exist) is to create an index:

```
CREATE INDEX ljqfw_booking_availability_IX1 
  ON ljqfw_booking_availability (unit_id, availdate)
```

Without an index available, the UPDATE statement is doing a full scan of the table, looking for rows that satisfy the predicates in the WHERE clause. An appropriate index gives MySQL a much more efficient way to locate the rows that satisfy the conditions in the WHERE clause, without having to examine every flipping row in the table.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are updating a great many rows in your table with each query. The rows have different `availdate` column values.

Here are some things to try.

First, try changing your query to work like this:

```
UPDATE ljqfw_booking_availability 
   set availability = 0 
 where unit_id=7520
   and availability <> 0   /* add this term to your query */
   and availdate IN (/*that dirty great list of dates*/)
```

This will eliminate MySQL's update overhead in circumstances where the query would do nothing. That is, it will refrain from updating the rows where `availability` is already zero. That may help, and it's easy to try.

Second, you say you have an index on `availdate`. Try adding a compound index on `(unit_id, availdate)`. Your update query, and mine, should be able to exploit that index rapidly to locate the rows needing updating. This should help a lot.

Third, it looks like your update query has a sequence of consecutive dates in it, and so can be recast as follows:

```
UPDATE ljqfw_booking_availability 
   set availability = 0 
 where unit_id=7520
   and availability <> 0  
   and availdate >= '2013-09-13'
   and availdate <= '2016-09-16'
```

If this consecutive-date optimization can be made to work for you and you keep the compound index I suggested, it should help your performance greatly. This is worth doing quite a lot of PHP programming.

Comment: Thanks Ollie, by adding availability <> 0 and adding indexes on the unit_id and availdate fields, it has sped up the query by a factor of about 10.   The list of dates is not necessarily consecutive - basically I am seperating the 'available' and 'not available' dates into 2 seperate update queries.  I will take a look at creating a compound index.  Thanks for your help, have been at this for days!!